# Histograms of bin for each group in a dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe say df1 of 2 column grp and bin

```
grp     bin
============
1       [0-100]
1       [101-200]
1       [101-200]
1       [201-300]
2       [301-400]
2       [301-400]
2       [401-500]
3       [401-500]
3       [401-500]
3       [501-600]
```

I want to split this dataframe in 3 groups and plot the bin frequency
in each group using ggplot. Esssentially I want 3 histogram (i.e. one for each
group) showing bin frequency as below

```
grp     bin       Hist freq
============================
1      [0-100]     1
1      [101-200]   2
2      [301-400]   2
```

I am trying to split the dataframe and than plot the histogram for each of the group as below

```
x <- split(df1,as.factor(df1$grp))
plothist <-function(pl) {ggplot(pl,aes(x=bin))+ geom_histogram()}
lapply(x,plothist)
```

It is not working and I am getting error as below:

> Error in .Call.graphics(C_palette2, .Call(C_palette2, NULL)) :
>   invalid graphics state

I would also like each bin bar to be of different color.

How can I do it ?

Comment: You can use `?table`

Comment: Is this something what you are after `ggplot(data=df1,aes(x=bin,fill=bin)) + geom_bar(aes(y=..count..)) + facet_wrap('grp')` ?

Comment: Thanks Pekka, it worked.